# Why do I have a large swapfile2 on my system?

Tags: linux, swap

I'm running a Digital Ocean Droplet running Debian 11 with 2Gb of memory, and there is a file /swapfile2 that is 6Gb in size, but I don't understand why it's there.

There is a /swapfile that is is 2Gb in size, which I understand as `sudo swapon --show`  gives me:

```
NAME      TYPE SIZE   USED PRIO
/swapfile file   2G 806.6M   -2
```

/etc/fstab just contains the following:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
UUID=021b447d-7a17-4df8-a938-c6d9fe566954       /       ext4    errors=remount-ro       0       1

/swapfile none swap sw 0 0
```

Why is this file there and can I delete it?

Comment: You can check which processes (if any) has the file in use with lsof /swapfile2

Comment: Thanks @eKKiM, that was helpful. It shows nothing is using it currently.

Comment: Actually stat shows me the file was last accessed months ago, so I think I'm fine to delete it, but I'm still interested as to how it got created, as nothing in the swapfile settings would indicate why a second file got created.

Comment: It's a [swapfile](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=swapfile+linux). No process is accessing it - the kernel is. It is created during installation. I would suggest reading and understanding what swap is.

Comment: @vidarlo I know it's a swapfile (see my use of the swapon command in my question). I didn't install Debian, it's an image created with the droplet, and I'm pretty sure Digital Ocean don't ship droplets with 6Gb swapfiles left lying around. None of the swapfile settings would indicate the use of 2 swapfiles, which is why I'm confused.